# AUTO-DELETE ROW 1 Day After Inserted (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, auto-delete

How to create event Auto-Delete some row 1 day after inserting that row?

I have 3 fields:

- id varchar
- name varchar
- timestamp current_timestamp()

Comment: What does 1 day mean - 24 hours? or is it ok to delete and item which is created at 23:59 at 00:01 the next day? or for simplicity delete 2 days (by date) later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your scripts.

```
Insert into table1 (id, name, timestamp) values (1, 'test', now())
```

after insert

```
Delete from table1 WHERE timestamp < now() - interval 1 day;
```

Comment: This will execute on the entire table every time a new row is inserted.  Mysql event is the right solution.

Comment: @Allen King, so far user didn't mention the frequency of inserts, so this solution is enough.

Answer (score 7):

Please take a look at Event: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-syntax.html
in your case:
you can try this one:

```
-- create a timer to update this table automatically

DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `et_update_your_trigger_name`;
CREATE EVENT `et_update_your_trigger_name`  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE 
STARTS '2010-01-01 00:00:00' 
DO 
DELETE FROM `DB_NAME`.`table_name` where DATEDIFF(now(),`timestamp`) > 1;

ALTER EVENT `et_update_your_trigger_name` ON  COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE;
```

this sql code create a trigger, and execute every minutes.

Comment: If the record is not expected to be deleted exactly 24 hr after insertion,  there is no need to run this every minute.  If the requirement is that a row needs to be deleted the next "day", running this event every 12 hr or even once a day should suffice.

Comment: An event is not a trigger this link is more appropriate https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html and don't forget to enable the event scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```